Wrong message error, while trying to adapt multiple overlaid rectangles as TikZ node code
I'm trying to adapt this question's answer to my code.
The problem is that it doesn't compile, and the message error is strange:

LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.

For the line where we have \end{frame}, below.
Here's my code:
    \documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation> {
\usetheme{AnnArbor}
\usecolortheme{beaver}
}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{graphicx}



\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                % automata,
                % chains,
                decorations.pathreplacing, 
                calligraphy,% had to be load after decorations.pathreplacing
                positioning,
                shapes,
                shadows,
                arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
    \begin{figure}
            \begin{tikzpicture}[
                node distance=2cm, 
                multiple/.style = {
                    double copy shadow={
                        shadow xshift=1ex,shadow yshift=-1.5ex,
                        draw=black!30
                    },
                    fill=white,draw=black,thick
                },
                % ordinary/.style = {rectangle,draw,thick}
            ]
                \node[multiple, label={\small Source Files}] (source_files) {
                    import math\\
                    result = math.exp(1)\\
                    print("math.exp(1):", result)\\
                    \dots
                };
                \node[multiple, label={\small Object Files}] (object_files) [right=of source_files] {
                    00000100010\\
                    01010100111\\
                    01110010110\\
                    \dots
                };
                \node[ordinary, label={\small Executable Files}] (exec_files) [right=of object_files] {
                    00000100010\\
                    01010100111\\
                    01110010110\\
                    \dots
                };                
                % Arrows
                \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}, thick] (source_files) -- (object_files) node[midway, above] {Compiler};
                \draw[-{Latex[length=3mm, width=2mm]}, thick] (object_files) -- (exec_files) node[midway, above] {Linker};    
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \caption{From Assembly to machine executable instructions.}
        \label{High Level}
    \end{figure}

\end{frame}

\end{document}


Please trim this down to a minimal example (10-20 lines) that exhibits the error.

Many of the packages in your preamble aren't necessary in a beamer document. Beamer also doesn't have  a floating mechanism, so specifying [ht] won't do anything useful.

The code compiles without error if an align option is given to the nodes. For example, if align=left, is placed after each occurrence of \node[.

Hi, many thanks for your answer. Do you know why it works ?

@Anoldmaninthesea. The contents of the nodes contain \\  thus an align option is needed to make \\  work.
